# Configure interpolated list in Terraform variable to create SNS subscriptions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to configure a list at the top of my file to list all the SQS resources that should subscribe to a SNS topic. It throws a "resource variables must be three parts: TYPE.NAME.ATTR"

I used locals because it seems they support interpolated values while variables did not.

```
locals {
    update-subscribers = [
        "${var.prefix}-${terraform.workspace}-contribution-updates"
      ]
}
```

Here is a snippet of my sns topic subscription.

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "subscription" {
  count = "${length(locals.update-subscribers.*)}"
  topic_arn = "${aws-sns-update-topic.topic.arn}"
  protocol = "sqs"
  endpoint = "arn:aws:sqs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${element(locals.update-subscribers, count.index)}"
  endpoint_auto_confirms = true
}
```

It would be nice to be able to use my variable list so I can switch around the workspaces without having any issues on the AWS site. All examples I can find point to a static list of CIDR settings, while I want my list to be based on the interpolated strings. I also tried

```
locals.contribution-update-subscribers[count.index]
```

Terraform did not like that either. How should my file be setup to support this or can it be supported?

Comment: Can you post the exact, unedited error? Post multiple against different configs if the error message changes in a meaningful way. It also might help to show what version of Terraform you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the configuration given here:

- The object name for accessing local values is called `local`, not `locals`.
- You don't need to (and currently, cannot) use the splat syntax to count the number of elements in what is already a list.

Addressing both of these would give the following configuration, which I think should work:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "subscription" {
  count = "${length(local.update-subscribers)}"

  topic_arn              = "${aws_sns_update_topic.topic.arn}"
  protocol               = "sqs"
  endpoint               = "arn:aws:sqs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.update-subscribers[count.index])}"
  endpoint_auto_confirms = true
}
```

Although dashes are allowed in identifiers in the Terraform language to allow the use of different naming schems in other systems, the idiomatic style is to use underscores for names defined within Terraform itself, such as your local value name `update-subscribers`.

Comment: Yes this worked. I'm about 4 hours into Terraform and missed that part. Thanks also for the recommendation on the dashes vs underscores. 

I did have to update my topic_arn as it is always aws_sns_topic then the resource name, then arn. It was obvious to me in the docs.